# How to display descendants in XML with Perl's XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, children

I am a 2 week old Perl user and I am trying to parse a 300 mb nested XML file. So please excuse my lack of knowledge. The file follows a similar format as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <APP:Report xsi:schemaLocation="WWW" xmlns:xsi="WWW" xmlns:APP="WWW">
   <library>
    <elt>
     <Book>The book of pages</Book>
     <Snap></Snap>
     <Line1>The Beginning</Line1>
     <Line2>We ceased to exist</Line2>
     <Line3>Accept it</Line3>
     <Line4>Now we live</Line4>
     <Line5>We reject it</Line5>
     <Rating>
      <C1>6.1</C1>
      <C2>8.9</C2>
      <C3>9.4</C3>
     </Rating>
    </elt>
    <Author>Sally</Author>
    <Publisher>Penguin</Publisher>
    <elt>
     <Book>The song</Book>
     <Snap></Snap>
     <Line1>This is how we do it</Line1>
     <Line2>I hope this works</Line2>
     <Line3>Please do</Line3>
     <Line4>Begging you</Line4>
     <Line5>Bye</Line5>
     <Rating>
      <C1>2.3</C1>
      <C2>9.9</C2>
      <C3>4.5</C3>
     </Rating>
    </elt>
    <Author>Justin</Author>
    <Publisher>Victoria</Publisher>
   </library>
  </APP:Report>
```

I want to be able to able to display Book, Snap, Line1, Line2, line3, Line4, line5, C1, C2 and C3 in different columns of the first row, Author in row 2 and Publisher in row 3. This is just a sample of the big file that I have. I do not want to access a specific child to display. I want to be able to display all its descendants.

Currently it is printing all my data row 1 column 1. My code snippet is enclosed below. What would be the best way to do this? I would gratefully appreciate any advice. Thank you!

```
    my $twig= new XML::Twig();
$twig->parsefile( $_);    # build the twig 
  foreach my $elt ($twig->root->children)
  {
  print $fout1 $elt->text."\n";
}
```

Edited the question: What if I had nested children within nested children? What would be the most efficient to do it? For example how do I access the elements of elt for each C? My 2nd question is about how I could display these elements like

```
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C1.X|
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C1.Y|
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C2.X|
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C2.Y|
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C3.X|
  The book of pages|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C3.Y|
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  The song|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C2.X|
  The song|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C2.Y|
  Example 
    <Rating>
      <C1>
        <elt>
         <X></X>
         <X></X>
         </elt>
        <elt>
        <elt>
      </C1>
      <C2>
        <elt>
        <elt>
        <elt>
      </C2>
      <C3>
        <elt>
        <elt>
        <elt>
      </C3>
     </Rating>
```

Like ikegami suggested, the easiest way to do this would be to create a handler for rating. But the issue is the time taken to parse this. The file I want to parse is 300 mb and has around 20 such routines like ratings. So I parse the big routine once, and then parse a part of the big routine 20 times. Is there another way to do this? Is there another XML module that can be more helpful than XML::Twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the nodes matching XPath

```xml
descendant:*[count(*)=0]
```

aka

```xml
.//*[count(*)=0]
```

relative to an `elt` element. I use XML::LibXML, so I'd do

```
$elt_node->findnodes("descendant:*[count(*)=0]")
```

A similar solution should be possible with XML::Twig. (It does have `findnodes`.)

---

ug, I forgot how bad XML::Twig's support for XPath is. It doesn't know about `count`, and `*` matches non-elements. No problem, we'll just have to do the work ourselves.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::Twig qw( );

my @eles = qw( Book Snap Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4 Line5 C1 C2 C3 );

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => {
      '/APP:Report/library/elt' => sub {
         my ($twig, $ele) = @_;

         my %row =
            map { $_->name() => $_->text() // '' }
               # $ele->findnodes("descendant:*[count(*)=0]")
               grep { $_->name() ne '#PCDATA' && ( grep { $_->name() ne '#PCDATA' } $_->children ) == 0 }
                  $ele->descendants();

         say join '|', @row{@eles};

         $twig->purge();  # Free unneeded memory.
      },
   },
);

say join '|', @eles;    
$twig->parsefile('my_big.xml');
```

Output:

```
Book|Snap|Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5|C1|C2|C3
The book of pages||The Beginning|We ceased to exist|Accept it|Now we live|We reject it|6.1|8.9|9.4
The song||This is how we do it|I hope this works|Please do|Begging you|Bye|2.3|9.9|4.5
```

Comment: I am amazed at how efficiently this is done! Wow. Thank you! Is there another way I can do it without using twig_handlers as I have others part of the document that I need to parse as well?

Comment: The whole point of using XML::Twig is large file support through `twig_handlers`

Comment: So you wouldn't suggest using XML::Twig if I had to parse the entire file? I had one more question. What does $_->name() ne '#PCDATA'  do?

Comment: It's not bad. Very slow, and cimmolèrent mishandles namespaces,  but the code isn't too bad with the notable exception encountered in this Answer.  #PCDATA is returned for text nodes

Comment: Thank you! I slightly edited my question. Could you help me with this? How can I modify my #row to display this?

Comment: Create a handler for Rating. Loop over its children (C1, C2 and C3). In the loop, loop over their children

Comment: Ikegami I tried this. Works well. But I have 20 routines like rating with different nested levels and children. Having a different twig handler for these is taking a lot of time to finish processing. Any way of manipulating the hash row to do this?

Comment: You can use multiple twig handlers, or just for the base element + digging on your own. Whatever you find best. Not sure what you mean by time, or to what hash you are referring